# How do I remove the dome of this light fixture?

Tags: lighting, kitchens

How do I go about removing the dome to replace the lights. I found online that similar light fixtures, one of the 3 "fingers" have a spring. But on mine, that doesn't seem to be the case. I tried, quite forcefully, pushing it in multiple directions, even at different angles. Nothing I've tried seems to work. I have no idea what brand light fixture these are, though Maxim do have similar looking ones.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can the little tabs at the bottom of the white cylinders rotate/move in any way? Is the silver bit on top of the white cylinders a nut, screw, or bolt head?

Comment: The tabs do not move. There seems to be screws facing the ceiling.

Comment: Have you tried loosening the screws (using an [offset screw driver](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-1-2-in-Offset-Screwdriver-74353/100038024) might work), to see if the tabs move when the screws are loosened?

Comment: from your pic, it looks like there is a screw in each of the holders? just try unscrewing them..

Answer (score 1):

those bits of metal you see on each claw are unlikely to be for fixing to the ceiling.  they're probably fasteners for the claw to the base - which would indicate that the claws can be rotated (as to release the cover).
there might be a trick to their rotation such as only one direction or pull-down-then-rotate...